# how to make tap to open slidable using flutter_slidable package?

Tags: flutter

to achieve this

[image]

currently I use this code below

```
          Slidable(
              child: ProductListItem(product: product),
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                motion: const StretchMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: (context) {
                      //
                    },
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.edit,
                    label: "edit".tr(),
                  ),
                  SlidableAction(
                    onPressed: (context) {
                      //
                    },
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Icons.delete,
                    label: "delete".tr(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

I need to swipe in the right side to open that `endPaneActions`.

what I want is ....

if I tap that list item, then it will programmatically open that `endPaneActions`. how to do that?

from the tutorial on Youtube in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuScuU3Vqlc&t=403s) , it seems I can use the code below

```
final slidable = Slidable.of(context);
final isClosed = slidable.renderingMode == SlidableRenderingMode.none;

if (isClosed) {
   slidable.open();
}
```

but it seems that code is obsolete, I can't find `.renderingMode` method on version 1.2.0

what is the latest version to programmatically open 'end actions pane' ?

Answer (score 4):

finally I can make tap to open slidable programmatically on version 1.2.0. I got a clue from [austin's answer on Github](https://github.com/letsar/flutter_slidable/issues/300#issuecomment-1021240978)

```
           Slidable(
              child: LayoutBuilder( // <---- add LayoutBuilder
                builder: (contextFromLayoutBuilder, constraints) {
                  return GestureDetector( // <--- add Gesture Detector
                    child: YourListItem(), // <--- your list item in here
                    onTap: () {

                      final slidable = Slidable.of(contextFromLayoutBuilder);
                      slidable?.openEndActionPane(
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        curve: Curves.decelerate,
                      );

                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              endActionPane: ActionPane( // <--- I use endActionPane in here
                motion: const StretchMotion(),
                children: [],
              ),
         )
```

as you can see, I add `LayoutBuilder` and `GestureDetector` inside the `Slidable` widget. `LayoutBuilder` is used to get the 'latest' context inside the `Slidable` widget, so the `slidable` value will not be null.

NOTE:
I use `endActionPane` here, so I use `openEndActionPane` method. if you use `startActionPane`, then you should use `openStartActionPane` method instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
Slidable(
  endActionPane: ActionPane(
    motion: const ScrollMotion(),
    children: [
      SlidableAction(
        onPressed: onPressed,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        icon: Icons.delete,
        label: 'Delete',
      ),
    ],
  ),
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) => InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        final controller = Slidable.of(context)!;
        final isClosed = controller.actionPaneType.value == ActionPaneType.none; // you can use this to check if its closed
        if (isClosed) {
          // use this to open it
          controller.openEndActionPane();
        } else {
          // if you want to close the ActionPane
          controller.close();
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```